# PHP - Sorting ArrayObject

Tags: php, sorting, arrayobject

I'm having a problem with sorting items in a PHP class that extends ArrayObject.

I am creating my classes, and the only way I've figured out to add the cmp() function is to put it in the same file, but outside of the class. I can't seem to put it anyplace else because of the way uasort requires the function name as a string.

So I'm doing this:

```
class Test extends ArrayObject{

    public function __construct(){
        $this[] = array( 'test' => 'b' );
        $this[] = array( 'test' => 'a' );
        $this[] = array( 'test' => 'd' );
        $this[] = array( 'test' => 'c' );
    }


    public function sort(){
        $this->uasort('cmp');
    }

}

function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['test'] == $b['test']) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $a['test'] < $b['test'] ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Which is fine if I'm only using one class like this, but if I use two (either by autoloading or require) then it breaks on trying to invoke cmp() twice.

I guess my point is it just seems like a bad way to do this. Is there any other way I can keep the `cmp()` function inside the class itself?

Comment: I know I could call them different things but that seems like not such a great solution either.

Comment: Create a util.php file that contains this function and other similar utility function. Then require_once('util.php'); when you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do this, instead of calling a function just make it an anonymous function.

> PHP 5.3.0 or higher only

```
class Test extends ArrayObject{

    public function __construct(){
        $this[] = array( 'test' => 'b' );
        $this[] = array( 'test' => 'a' );
        $this[] = array( 'test' => 'd' );
        $this[] = array( 'test' => 'c' );
    }


    public function sort(){
        $this->uasort(function($a, $b) {
            if ($a['test'] == $b['test']) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return $a['test'] < $b['test'] ? -1 : 1;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As anonymous functions only work on PHP 5.3.0 or higher, this would be the more compatible option if you need to target PHP versions below 5.3.0

> Below PHP 5.3.0

```
class Test extends ArrayObject{

    public function __construct(){
        $this[] = array( 'test' => 'b' );
        $this[] = array( 'test' => 'a' );
        $this[] = array( 'test' => 'd' );
        $this[] = array( 'test' => 'c' );
    }


    public function sort(){
        $this->uasort(array($this, 'cmp'));
    }

    public function cmp($a, $b) {
        if ($a['test'] == $b['test']) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return $a['test'] < $b['test'] ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: damn, this is interesting, I swore I tried this and it didn't work. Thanks, this is a perfectly workable solution.

Comment: what version of php are you using? Anonymous functions didn't become available until PHP 5.3.0

Comment: Good point for those that far back. I'm on 5.3.2 (fortunately for this, unfortunately in general).

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this was right in the PHP docs (user comments section) -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

**magikMaker 4 years ago**
*a quick reminder on the syntax if you want to use uasort in a Class or Object:*

```
<?php 

// procedural: 
uasort($collection, 'my_sort_function'); 

// Object Oriented 
uasort($collection, array($this, 'mySortMethod')); 

// Objet Oriented with static method 
uasort($collection, array('self', 'myStaticSortMethod')); 

?>
```

Comment: I was in the process of typing this out. +1 for actually reading the manual (and comments). Plus, [the manual](http://php.net/uasort) says see [usort](http://php.net/usort) for details of the compare function and on that page there is [an example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#function.usort.examples.object) accessing a static class.

Comment: I guess the real deep answer is here in learning about the "callable" type here:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php